# How to select all subclasses of jquery widget

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-selectors, widget

I have a custom component derived from jquery widget

```
$.widget("custom.component", {
  // Some code
}
```

and extended sub-component

```
$.widget("custom.subcomponent", $.custom.component,{
  // Some code
}
```

Question is how can I select all components in the document regardless if it is instance of `custom.component` or `custom.subcomponent` ?

Comment: `$('.myWidgetComponentClass')`

Comment: Do I get it right that only way is to add custom class to every component I create ?  `$(':custom-component')` is not working for me.

Comment: `$(':custom-component')` is not valid syntax. Adding class will certainly be easiest way. Look at jQUery UI , every widget can be found by it's component class